# Select part of text after it's been added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$sel = 'lorem ipsum';
jQuery(this).html('<p>Hello world ' + $sel +' great day!');
```

So the `.html()` is added via ajax.

I want the `$sel` text to be selected when it's **output** on the page (as if the user highlighted it with their cursor).

I have the following code to select elements:

```
function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = doc.getElementById(element)
        , range, selection
    ;    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

How can I use that code and select just the text within `$sel`? So, output the html and select the `$sel` part.

Comment: I'll bounty this with 50 points once it's eligible for a working solution.

Comment: You have not used end tag `</p>`

Comment: That's not how bounties work. Bounties are promises. Set one now or don't set one now.

Comment: @Tomalak You can only set a bounty 2 days after your question is posted. If you look through my recent questions, you'll see that whenever I've promised a bounty, I have started the bounty. In fact, I think I've done 3 bounties just this week :)

Comment: True, I did not think of the two day delay. It's a rather unusual thing to promise bounties ahead of time though. I still think that's not how they were *meant* to be used, but well. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't set a bounty for this one, @HenrikPetterson :(

Comment: Where's my bounty, man!? It's been more than four-and-a-half years. You accepted my answer but didn't give the promised bounty. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function below (*`createSelectedSpan`*) accepts a single argument, `value`. Every time this function is called, a new local variable `sel`, with the value of `span` element, is created. The `sel`'s innerHTML is set to the value of argument `value`. Then, `sel` is adopted as a child by `body`. And at last `sel` is selected.

Besides this, I've modified your `SelectText` function to set the variable `text` defined inside it to the `DOM Node` passed to it as an argument.

This function can be called multiple times without any error with the newly added element being selected and other elements being deselected.

```js
  function SelectText(element) {
  var doc = document,
    text = element,  // A modification is made here
    range, selection;
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(text);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}

function createSelectedSpan(value){
  var sel = document.createElement("span");
  sel.innerHTML = value;

  $("body").append(sel);

  
  SelectText(sel);
}

createSelectedSpan("hello world");
setTimeout(function(){createSelectedSpan("hello world2")},5000); //called second time
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the element through jQuery and then select the element you just inserted. That way you always target whatever it is that you're inserting at the moment.

```js
var sel = $('<span>').html('lorem ipsum');
$('body').html('<p>Hello world <span class="insertion-point"></span> great day!</p>');
$('body').find('.insertion-point').after(sel);
var toSelect = sel.get(0);

if (document.body.createTextRange) {
 range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(toSelect);
    range.select();
} else if (window.getSelection) {
 selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(toSelect);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ideally, I would like to target the specific span tag which I output via .html(), but the problem is that I will output similar html with its respective span tag on the same page at different points, meaning that I need to find a way to target this specific one because I can't have multiple tags with the same ID.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I changed my answer so that it targets whatever it is you inserted, no id's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The function "SelectText" which you are using is fine.
I think the solution can be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $sel = 'lorem ipsum';
    $('#feedback').html('<p>Hello world <span id="selection">'+ $sel +'</span> great day!</p>');
    SelectText('selection');  
});
```

Comment: I don't want to target the ID but the specific span tag that I'm outputting via .html() -- I will output html() like this quite often so I can't use the same ID twice. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the $sel in **any** custom tag, doesn't matter which one, for example x.

```
this.innerHTML = '<p>Hello world <x>' + $sel +'</x> great day!');
```

And then simply highlight it. Since **this** contains only the **p** tag, you can reference it descending directly from **this** through the **p** tag onto the **x** tag, which contains the **$sel** value. You don't have to worry about other **x** tags on the webpage since you start looking from **this** downwards. You will always find exactly 1 **p** tag and inside it only **x** tag.

```
var selection = window.getSelection();        
var range = document.createRange();
var p = this.children[0]; // 'children' ignores Text nodes unlike 'childNodes'
var x = p.children[0];
range.selectNodeContents(x);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

Tadaa.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is fine, so the easiest way to select it is to call it once your Ajax is finished. Just listen for the event to fire and call the function.

This should be done this way :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// do stuff

// listen to the loading to be finished
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        try
        {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) 
            {           
             /* here your loading is finished, call the function
                on the id of the element which received the text */
             SelectText('yourElement');
            }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
        alert(e.message);
        }
    };
```

So just after the loading is finished i.e. when the text is **outputted** on your page, the text will be highlighted. Voila !

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the new element within a span tag:

with Jquery:

```
$sel = 'lorem ipsum';
jQuery(this).html( '<p>Hello world <span id=\"selectedSpan\">' + $sel +'</span> great day!</p>')

jQuery("#selectedSpan").css('color','red')
jQuery("#selectedSpan").css('background','yellow')
```

This way you can choose whatever style you want it to look like.

Answer (score -3):

The best approach is to use CSS for this purpose.

```js
var text = "Bla Bla";
$('body').append("<p>Text Before, <span class='highlight'>" + text + "</span>, Text After</p>");
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question. :)